# Counting instances of a string in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have figured out two different ways of counting instances of a string within my dataframe (banks) through using either:

```
sum(str_count(banks$names, "Example Bank Name")) #produces a singular result
#or
summary(as.factor(banks$names) #produces all results
```

Both spit out answers to the console. With the 2nd option I can save it as a list, but ideally I'd like to have a dataframe that contains two columns: the name of bank and the count of instances it appears. Trying to use as.data.frame() command for the list produces a dataframe with 1 column.

I'm looking for suggestions to either improve how I'm counting string instances, or how to convert a list to a dataframe as mentioned above.

Comment: Sounds like you want `as.data.frame(table(banks$name))` or `dplyr::count(banks, name)`